# Arduino RTC subtracting 1 second every 8 hours

Tags: c++, arduino

I used the RTC, from an Arduino MKR 1300 with integrated RTC, as an alarm that will trigger a "boolean"(it's an integer) that will tell the loop to run a certain method every minute and then send some data every 5 minutes. It's on an active loop but the method to send data ONLY WORKS if it's inside the loop (no idea why). The problem is the RTC apparently is subtracting 1 second at every 8 hours or so after a few days the timing might come off and instead of sending data every xx:10:xx-xx:15:xx it might send data xx:09:xx-xx:14:xx.

Here's the code:

```
#include <EmonLib.h>
#include <RTCZero.h>
#include <MKRWAN.h>


EnergyMonitor emon1;
EnergyMonitor emon2;
EnergyMonitor emon3;
RTCZero rtc;
LoRaModem modem;

String appEui = "1234567891011121";
String appKey = "ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff";

/* INITIAL_TIME */
const byte seconds = 0;
const byte minutes = 0;
const byte hours = 0;
const byte day = 17;
const byte month = 12;
const byte year = 18;


byte second_alarm = 0;
byte minute_alarm = 0;
byte hour_alarm = 0;
byte INTERVAL = 60;
int SEND_LOOP = 5;

int totalKW;
int counter= 0;
int alarm_Triggered = 0;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  if (!modem.begin(EU868)) {
    Serial.println("Failed to start module");
    while (1) {}
  };
  Serial.print("Your module version is: ");
  Serial.println(modem.version());
  Serial.print("Your device EUI is: ");
  Serial.println(modem.deviceEUI());

  Serial.println("Connecting");
  int connected = modem.joinOTAA(appEui, appKey);
  if (!connected) {
    Serial.println("Something went wrong; are you indoor? Move near a window and retry");
    while (1) {}
  }
  Serial.println("Connected");

  // Set poll interval to 60 secs.
  modem.minPollInterval(60);

  analogReadResolution(9);
  emon1.current(1, 53);
  emon2.current(2, 53);
  emon3.current(3, 53);
  counter= 0;

  rtc.begin(); // initialize RTC

  rtc.setAlarmTime(hour_alarm, minute_alarm, second_alarm);
  rtc.enableAlarm(rtc.MATCH_HHMMSS);
  rtc.attachInterrupt(triggerAlarm);

  // Set the time
  rtc.setHours(hours);
  rtc.setMinutes(minutes);
  rtc.setSeconds(seconds);

  // Set the date
  rtc.setDay(day);
  rtc.setMonth(month);
  rtc.setYear(year);


}

void loop() {
  if (alarm_Triggered == 1) {
    dataMonitor();
    alarm_Triggered = 0;
  }
}

void dataMonitor() {

  int totalWatt = 0;
  unsigned long delay_send = 0;
  int sending = 0;

  double Irms1 = emon1.calcIrms(600);
  if (Irms1 < 0.3) Irms1 = 0;
  double Watt1 = Irms1 * 230;

  double Irms2 = emon2.calcIrms(600);
  if (Irms2 < 0.3) Irms2 = 0;
  double Watt2 = Irms2 * 230;

  double Irms3 = emon3.calcIrms(600);
  if (Irms3 < 0.3) Irms3 = 0;
  double Watt3 = Irms3 * 230;

  totalWatt = Watt1 + Watt2 + Watt3;
  totalKW = totalKW + totalWatt / 1000;
  Serial.println(counter);

  sendDataChecker(Irms1, Irms2, Irms3);
  setAlarm();
  counter= counter+ 1;

}

void sendDataChecker(double Irms1, double Irms2, double Irms3) {
  if (counter== SEND_LOOP) {
    double IrmsTotal = Irms1 + Irms2 + Irms3;
    String msg = "{\"id\":\"avac_aud2\",\"kW\":" + String(totalKW) + ", \"current\":" + String(IrmsTotal) + "}";
    int err;
    Serial.println("Ready to Send");
    modem.beginPacket();
    modem.print(msg);
    err = modem.endPacket(true);
    Serial.println("Sent1");
    if (err > 0) {
      //message sent correctly
      Serial.println("Sent");
      counter= 0;
      totalKW = 0;
    } else {
      Serial.println("ERR");
      counter= 0;
    }
  }
}


void setAlarm() {
  second_alarm += INTERVAL;
  if (second_alarm >= 60) {
    minute_alarm++;
    second_alarm = 0;
  }
  if (minute_alarm >= 60) {
    hour_alarm++;
    minute_alarm = 0;
  }
  if (hour_alarm >= 24) {
    hour_alarm = 0;
  }

  rtc.setAlarmTime(hour_alarm, minute_alarm, second_alarm);
}

void triggerAlarm() {
  alarm_Triggered = 1;
}
```

Comment: Concerning Arduino and RTC, I googled [arduino rtc precision](https://www.google.com/search?q=arduino+rtc+precision) and found e.g. a discussion in the arduino forum [Accuracy of DS1307 Real Time Clock module](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=87846.0). At the first glance, it looks like you are not the only one with this issue. May be, the Arduino forum is the better place to ask for your issue.

Comment: My board is an MKR 1300 with an integrated RTC so I would assume that problem was not actually a problem here, +- accuracy every time would be okay by me, but to me this looks like it might be a coding issue, I just have no idea where. Also will edit post to add the board. Either way will also add a question to the arduino forum to see how well it fares.

Comment: A possible programming issue could be floating point accuracy - your time values are all `byte` i.e. integral. Another issue could be that you lose periodically milliseconds by adding durations. If I understood your code right you increment the alarm time (by a certain amount) and set it to RTC again (for next "wake up") i.e. working with time points. TLDR, the whole code looks (to me) not quite bad. If the alarms drift over time then I would bet on RTC inaccuracy.

Comment: Oh well, will keep on trying to figure this out, thanks for the help.

Comment: How did you realize the time drift? Became it visible in the reported time stamps? Did you report the time stamps of the Arduino RTC? I just realized: Assuming that RTC has a certain inaccuracy, it still should wake-up at the correct time points (as described in your question) indepedently how these time points differ from wall clock time. If this is not the case (RTC reported time stamps drift to xx4xx/xx9xx), then you are right and something might be wrong in your incrementation (or something else).

Comment: @Scheff I send the data to a database from a server, that once it reaches the server adds a timestamp with milliseconds. How did I notice it it's because the milliseconds gradually get reduced and the second got reduced by 1 after eight hours. I have another work that uses the arduino cpu and delay() but that one is off by 8/7 ms each minute (1 second reduce every 2 hours) because of the cpu's frequency but I managed to get it working by adding a random 7-8 ms every 1 minute, but that's an unreliable way to do this and so I wanted to get the RTC working.

Comment: I watched a bit closer onto your `setAlarm()`. I don't think it's wrong but IMHO not very maintenance friendly. Changing `INTERVAL` to anything else than 60 might break this code. I would suggest instead: `second_alarm += INTERVAL; minute_alarm += second_alarm / 60; second_alarm %= 60; hour_alarm += minute_alarm / 60; minute_alarm %= 60; hour_alarm %= 24;` There is no more `if` necessary what's usually a performance plus (even with some more arithmetic operations which are on most modern CPUs much faster than potential branches).

Comment: Good point will give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: If you send data triggered by Arduino RTC and store them with time-stamp of server, this really smells like RTC inaccuracy. To become sure, you could send periodically time-stamps of RTC to server and compare it with server wall clock time.

Comment: This brings me to a possible solution. The server may recognize Arduino RTC drift and send back values to correct it. (I assume the server can correct its own RTC via e.g. Internet time service or something similar.)

Comment: It's LoRa and it's inside an internal network so yes that is one solution but damn it's a pain in the ass one because I can only access the network from the inside and there are a s***ton of security protocols that I will need to look on the API both because of the internal network and the actual LoRa gateway access. This will be my last resort though.

Comment: Oha. LoRa (just learned something new). ;-) So, alternatively, you could try to quantify the drift of Arduino RTC and correct it periodically. (This is, of course, fruitless if it becomes more or less over time e.g. depending on outside temperature...) May be, even some Inc./Dec. buttons on the Arduino box for long time maintenance... ;-)

Comment: Yep that's what I did when using delay() with the arduino's actual cpu frequency. Oh well let's see, for one thing that other one with the 7-8ms delay that i corrected is still running at the same second interval for 24 hours so that might just be the solution.

Comment: There should be register `FREQCORR`, positive value speeds up the RTC oscillator and negative slow it down. I'd give a shot with that. But if everything you've tried is slower, maybe the other side is running too fast. And if you have the internet available, you can use NTP (network time protocol) to get current time.

Comment: @KIIV For a second that's what I thought too, I'm using a Raspberry PI as a server so maybe that was the problem but nope, the times in both the RPi and my usual desktop are exactly the same second by second. I will see if I can mess with that `FREQCORR`. Either way my other arduino running on delays with random 7 to 8ms increments seems to be working fine so I might just use that option.